# Error 32 (Broken Pipe)

Tags: ssd, pipe

I bought a Crucial SSD and when trying to back up my 2009 MacBook Pro (13") to it I get the error 32 broken pipe message and it will not copy. Any suggestions?

Comment: What program gives you this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem because I hadn't first initialised the drive.

The SSD should be represented on the left of DiskUtils as the device itself and then a sub-item representing the partition.

If you try to back your "Macintosh HD" onto the device (the parent item) you get this "Error 32 Broken Pipe" problem.  If you make a single blank partition and backup to there it should work fine.

Hope that helps anyone else googling for a solution :o)